# Why z-index is not working for div?

Tags: css, positioning

I am trying to get my footer to show on top of the footer background, but z-index seems not to be working. Does anyone see what is wrong with it? http://jsfiddle.net/f2ySC/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have to *explicitly* define the `position` property:

```
.footerBox {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 10px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin: 10px 0 -200px -10px;
    width: 1185px;
    z-index: 1000;

    position:relative;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f2ySC/1/

---

This brings the footer into the `current stacking context`:

> ... The root element forms the root stacking context. Other stacking
> contexts are generated by **any positioned element (including relatively
> positioned elements)** having a computed value of 'z-index' other than
> 'auto'. Stacking contexts are not necessarily related to containing
> blocks. In future levels of CSS, other properties may introduce
> stacking contexts, for example 'opacity' ...

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

Comment: 6 years later and this still helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

using negative margin is not a good practice. z-index:-1; works it just display the content on the background of another div :)

Comment: Creating a div child and setting the parent and child's z-index worked for me. Pity had to create an extra div between parent and chidren just to set the z-index. Also had to set the opacity and background color of this intermediate div

Answer (score 2):

Is this the effect you are looking for? [Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/f2ySC/4/)

I added `position: relative;` to `#footerBack` and `.footerBox` to enable `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

On footerBox set the `position` attribute to `absolute`
Your new code should read as follows

```
.footerBox {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 10px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin: 10px 0 -200px -10px;
    width: 1185px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

See a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f2ySC/2/)

Using `position: relative` also works