# Wordpress plugin z-index override not working

Tags: wordpress, css

I am using a WP plugin called "Post Snippets". This allows you to easily enter code into areas that a client would otherwise have no idea how to do. The code works just fine unless i call it from a model box that has a z-index set higher than itself. Then it shows up behind, leading you to believe it is not working. I can make some adjustments with Firebug and it works just fine. But no matter how i write the css, it will not override it. The Modal that appears is set with a z-index of 160000. The z-index that is somehow set to the Snippets modal is only 100000. 
http://grab.by/EZgE

So when I press Post Snippets from the gallery modal nothing happens because the POst Snippets dialog box show up behind the EnviraGallery modal box. I can see that the Snippets is set by .ui-dilaog and is set to a z-index of 100102. Even though I put this in the css

```
.ui-dialog {
    z-index:180000 !important;
}
```

nothing happens. I have tried many variations and still nothing.

The author of the plugin says this:

> The plugin doesn't have it's own styling for the jQuery dialog, but uses WordPress' default jQuery UI styling (ie, wp-jquery-ui-dialog). What dialog box does it come up behind?

There has to be a way to do this right? I am not much of a coder beyond this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Houston

Comment: Here is the css that see when looking at the Post Snippet modal.

http://grab.by/EZgI

Answer (score 0):

For z-index to have any effect you need to explicitly set the CSS `position` attribute of the element in question.

[Why z-index is not working for div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592323/why-z-index-is-not-working-for-div)

Comment: z-index seems to already be set and functioning. I am just trying to increase its value. So I am assuming that `position` is already set. A quick look at Firebug confirms this.